# i can't set web textbox value using wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, awesomium

hello i am doing an automation program. the start of the program is to login

and here is the html tag

```
<form name="LoginForm" method="post" action="https://admin">
   <input type="hidden" name="redirectURL" value="Admin/">
   <input type="hidden" name="reason" value="LOGIN_REQUIRED">

   <fieldset style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
     <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
           <th style="text-align: left">
              <label for="login">
                 E-mail Address
              </label>
           </th>
           <td style="width: 65%">
              <input type="text" name="login" maxlength="80" value="" id="login" style="width:98%">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>
              <div class="field_error" style="clear: left;">

              </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th style="text-align: left">
              <label for="password">
                 Password
              </label>
           </th>
           <td>
              <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="64" value="" style="width:98%">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td></td>
           <td>
              <div class="field_error" style="clear: left;">

              </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </table>

     <hr style="visibility: hidden;"/>

     <div style="width: 60px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Log In" style="text-align:center;" class="generic_button">
     </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

but why i can't set the value of the password textbox.

im using wpf and awesomium

i can set the textbox value of the username but i can't set the value of the password

here is my code

```
wb.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#login').value = '{0}'", txtUsername.Text));
wb.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('#password').value = '{0}'", txtPassword.Text));
```

how can i set the value of password? it doesn't use ID? thank you. it use name attribute

i tried using the built in webbrowser and i can make it work

here is the code:

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection elems = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
                foreach (System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement elem in elems)
                {
                    String nameStr = elem.GetAttribute("name");
                    if (nameStr != null && nameStr.Length != 0)
                    {
                        if (nameStr == "login")
                        {
                            elem.SetAttribute("value", txtUsername.Text);
                        }
                        if (nameStr == "password")
                        {
                            elem.SetAttribute("value", txtPassword.Text);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Edit:
Solution: i changed the awesomium to geckofx. and convert the code above with the code of geckofx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
wb.ExecuteJavascript(String.Format("document.querySelector('input[name=\"password\"]').value = '{0}'", txtPassword.Text));
```

JSFiddle can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/L4yrjfmz/

Comment: i tried your code but still it doesn't work. i doesn't give me error. it also doesn't add value to the password

Comment: It's seems to work on this JsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/L4yrjfmz/

Also saw that name='password' should be name=\"password\" (maybe thats the problem in my code)

Answer (score 3):

Look at your password input:

```
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="64" value="" style="width:98%">
```

it has no id attribute, in css selectors a `#` prefix refers to the id attribute, in your case you can use any of the following selectors for the password input:

```
input[type=password]

input[name=password]
```

Comment: it doesn't work. but when i use webbrowser control of the visual studio. it works